# Capturing live-filtered and unfiltered video simultaneously with CoreImage

Tags: ios, filter, preview, core-image

I have an iOS app in which I apply a CoreImage filter to a live camera preview. I would like to add a button that captures the live camera preview and saves a picture in the photo library, but I would also like to save an unfiltered image at the same (or nearly the same) timepoint. Do you all have suggestions about how best to do this, or have you seen similar question threads?
Thanks for your time!

So far, I have only tried using a screenshot-based approach - haven't tried anything yet as I'm not sure how best to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I usually build a pipeline for rendering.
To make two renderers such as filtered and passthrough. And then record both renderer.

```
Source -> Filter -> Filtered Rendering -> Record
       -> Passthrough Rendering -> Record
```